# creating several smoothgallery objects on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mootools, image-gallery

I have a website and I want to have several slide galleries on one page.
I am using javascript and smoothgallery to create the galleries. But I can't make it to work with several objects of galleries. It only shows one gallery and ignores the other one.

This is my javascript code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function startGallery() {
            var myGallery = new gallery($('myGallery'), {
                timed: false,
                useReMooz: true,
                embedLinks: false
            });
        }
        window.addEvent('domready',startGallery);
        function startGallery1() {
            var myGallery1 = new gallery($('myGallery1'), {
                timed: false,
                useReMooz: true,
                embedLinks: false
            });
        }
        window.addEvent('domready',startGallery1);
</script>
```

And this is my HTML code.

```
<div id="myGallery" style="float:right; text-align:left;">
            <div class="imageElement">
                <a href="samples2/1.jpg" title="open image" class="open"></a>
                <img src="samples2/1-gallery.jpg" class="full" />
                <img src="samples2/1-mini.jpg" class="thumbnail" />
            </div>
            <div class="imageElement">
                <a href="samples2/2.jpg" title="open image" class="open"></a>
                <img src="samples2/2-gallery.jpg" class="full" />
                <img src="samples2/2-mini.jpg" class="thumbnail" />
            </div>

</div>
<div id="myGallery1" style="float:left; text-align:left;">
            <div class="imageElement">
                <a href="samples2/3.jpg" title="open image" class="open"></a>
                <img src="samples2/3-gallery.jpg" class="full" />
                <img src="samples2/3-mini.jpg" class="thumbnail" />
            </div>
            <div class="imageElement">
                <a href="samples2/4.jpg" title="open image" class="open"></a>
                <img src="samples2/4-gallery.jpg" class="full" />
                <img src="samples2/4-mini.jpg" class="thumbnail" />
            </div>

</div>
```

How can I make it work and actually see myGallery and myGallery1 next to each other?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you prrecise which smoothgallery you are using? if its [the one I think about that is kind of](https://github.com/jon1012/smoothgallery/) is kind of old (MooTools 1.2). Also that domready functions are wrong, [they will not fire both](http://jsfiddle.net/Lavhkdb1/). Try this code instead of yours: http://jsfiddle.net/0n8sy3k3/

Comment: I am using MooTools 1.2 and I tried your code and still it ignores the second gallery.

Comment: Did you try the code I posted?

Comment: yes. it yield the same result as before. Still ignored the second gallery and only fired the first one.

Comment: but did you use only one `window.addEvent('domready', function(){` like i suggested? Any error in the console?

Comment: Yes. It shows the right gallery perfect and the left one, it just puts the pictures on the page without the gallery feature of smoothgallery.

Comment: @Sergio Can I contact you through your website for further assistant? I am really stuck here and I have to make work for my job.

Comment: Its Christmas Eve, I have not much time. Please put some efford into making a jsFiddle that reproduces the problem and we will look at it. Cheers.

Comment: That's right! sorry about that. Merry Christmas! Thanks!

Comment: @Sergio Thank you! your function worked great! the problem was with the second div. instead of calling the div myGallery1, it should be the same name as the first one (both should be id="myGallery". Thank you and again Merry Christmas.

Comment: You cannot have duplicate IDs! The solution is elsewhere... Merry X-mas to you too :)